# Regular expression to find a text as being a whole word

Tags: regex, abap

I am using the ABAP statement `READ REPORT` and I want to use `FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX`. Let's say for example I want to search for `SELECT` but when I do `FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX 'SELECT'`, the return table gets lines that have `SELECT-OPTIONS`, `SELECTION-SCREEN` and `SELECT`.

How do I use regex to get only those lines with `SELECT`, discarding the other 2 possible matches in the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go for `` `SELECT ` ``

Note the extra space and the use of grave quotes (grave quotes so that the trailing space is considered). This simple solution is feasible because it's highly unlikely that there's a new line right after SELECT.

Your requirement is so simple that you don't need to use a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks. I used `SELECT[[:space:]]` for this.

Comment: I corrected the answer from `'SELECT '` (trailing space ignored) which is the same as `'SELECT'`, to `\`SELECT \`` with grave quotes (trailing space considered). The solution `SELECT[[:space:]]` has the advantage to take into account tabulation, non-breaking space and a few other space-like characters too; it can also be written in its short form `SELECT\s`.

Answer (score 1):

http://sapignite.com/regex-in-abap/

OR

Download a PDF from this Link

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=how%20do%20i%20use%20regex%20in%20abap%20to%20search%20for%20a%20specific%20string%3F&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sdn.sap.com%2Firj%2Fscn%2Findex%3Frid%3D%2Flibrary%2Fuuid%2F902ce392-dfce-2d10-4ba9-b4f777843182%26overridelayout%3Dtrue&ei=AsFxT9bJNdDqrQfdoe3hDQ&usg=AFQjCNHTHvQXYtYosCLPwj98Za-LMJbo7w&cad=rja

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I have read the PDF in the link you provided and I admit I don't understand it yet. I was looking for a more specific answer so if it's okay with you, can you perhaps give me the regex value so my search matches `SELECT` only and not `SELECT-OPTIONS` and `SELECTION-SCREEN`?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\bselect\b
```

\b stands for word boundary. It will not match aselect or selected

look at a good regex reference at [mozila.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions) and try your regex at [regexpal](http://regexpal.com)

Comment: He ought to test in SAP, not in a browser, the SAP implementation does not match 100% the javascript one. \bSELECT\b does work.

Comment: `\bSELECT\b` does not match `SELECTION-SCREEN` but unfortuntately it matches `SELECT-OPTIONS` that the OP doesn't want.

Comment: BUT combined with ?! you may exclude words: `\b(?!SELECT-OPTIONS)SELECT\b`

Answer (score 1):

There is a very cool playground for testing regular expressions: Run Report DEMO_REGEX_TOY with SE38 or SE80.

Comment: Yup, `DEMO_REGEX_TOY` is an awesome tool to try out different Regex stuff.

Comment: TOY being the operative bit... it neglects to do regex escaping of replacement strings. Otherwise cute.